# Grails: How can I switch thousands grouping off for BigDecimal output

Tags: grails, bigdecimal, number-formatting

When rendering the value of a BigDecimal in a view, it renders with a comma as the thousands separator, which confuses my HTML5 "number" input. Is there a way I can turn the grouping off.

I'd like the number 1000 to render as 1000, not 1,000.

```
<div class="control-group ${hasErrors(bean:ourCompany,field:'turnover','error')}">
  <label class="control-label">Annual Turnover</label>
  <div class="controls">
    <input value="${stripFormatting(fieldValue(bean:ourCompany,field:'turnover'))}" name="turnover" id="annual-turnover" placeholder="0" type="number">
    <span class="help-inline bee-hide-error ${hasErrors(bean:ourCompany,field:'turnover','bee-show-error')}">This can only be a numeric field.</span>
    <p class="bee-help-text"> <i class="icon-info-sign"></i> Total company income for the last financial year</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Where do you output the number? In `stripFormatting(fieldValue(bean:ourCompany,field:'turnover'))`? Then you should show the code of those functions.

Answer (score 0):

try this:
Grails tag [formatNumber](http://grails.org/doc/2.2.0/ref/Tags/formatNumber.html), using Java's [DecimalFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html)